# How to check if an object is in a certain class before adding it to a HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I'm doing a project which involves a sport store class which contains managers and cashier class. The manager is the one who can add cashiers to their list, and they can set a certain cashier to be the employee of the month. Before adding the cashier to the Manager's list, I want to check if they are already added in the sport store class. If there are not in the Sport store class, then they cannot be added to the manager's list.

Here is a part of a class diagram that shows the classes:

[image: Sport store Class]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [`List#contains(obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) tells you if `obj` is already present in the list.

Comment: Did you go through the javadoc of a `Set`? There is a `contains` method which should help you.

Comment: Yes I know about this,but the issue is that I don't know how to specify the collection of the sportStore class through the Manager class

Comment: You're the programmer. Just don't add something that isn't of the proper class.

Comment: I think it would help to re-formulate your question with some actual code, to help outline what the actual requirement is, and showing which bit you're getting stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting the new element in the *HashSet* try to use the method *contains*.

[Official Documentation of Java about the contains method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

**Example**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)",
                "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.02)", "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.03)", "OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.04)" }));
        
        System.out.println(values.contains("OK (0.07, 0.05, 0.01)"));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
true
```